# How do I disable all keyboards for use on a tablet?

Tags: keyboard, battery, mate

using Ubuntu+MATE-20.xx desktop on a tablet and super happy with it -- almost.

It assumes I have a keyboard so it checks for battery levels of, I am guessing, a BT keyboard. I am forever getting "keyboard battery low 1%" messages that never go away until I click them.

I went into the Keyboard section and it lists a zillion different Brands of keyboards and models, but it is missing the important Brand of "None."

How do I tell Ubuntu or MATE it is OK not to have a keyboard and stop testing for non-existent batteries?

Comment: This was [an issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/-/issues/108) on GNOME maybe Mate hit [this upower issue](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/upower/upower/-/merge_requests/94). On 20.xx (X by default) try to [disable with `xinput`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91078/209677). On Wayland might work [libinput](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/configuration.html) or something [provided by the DE](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Libinput#Configuration)

Comment: Please be specific with release details; there is no 20.xx, and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS was the conclusion of the 18.10-19.04-19.10-20.04 two year *development* cycle; with 20.10 being from the **next** *development* cycle. 20.04 & 20.10 are from different *development* cycles (*each full two year full development cycle consists of 3 non-LTS and conclude with a LTS; thus 4 minor cycles within it*)

Comment: Does it need Bluetooth (I expect it does if it's a tablet, but I have seen similar issues on my laptop, where I only rarely use BT)? If not, just turning BT off should do the job.